# Trying to add image in MudBlazor carousel is not working

Tags: blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am trying to add an image to the carouselItem of MudBlazor. Its not working correctly taking wrong width and height as well.

My code:

```
</MudCarouselItem>
<MudCarouselItem Transition="transition" Color="@Color.Secondary">
    <div class="d-flex" style="height:100%">
        <MudIcon Class="mx-auto my-auto" Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor" Size="@Size.Large" />
    </div>
</MudCarouselItem>
<MudCarouselItem Transition="transition">
    <div class="d-flex" style="height:100%">
        <MudIcon Class="mx-auto my-auto" Icon="@Icons.Custom.Brands.MudBlazor" Color="@Color.Primary" Size="@Size.Large" />
    </div>
</MudCarouselItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok!, you should put your html or component inside, like this:

```
                <MudCarousel Style="height:500px; width:100%" ShowArrows="true" ShowDelimiters="true" AutoCycle="true" TData="object">

                    <MudCarouselItem Transition="Transition.Fade" Color="@Color.Transparent">
                 
                            <a href="@imageUrl.secure_url" target="_blank">
                                <img src="@your_image_url" width="500" height="500" alt="Italian Trulli">
                            </a>
                     
                    </MudCarouselItem>
                    
                </MudCarousel>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use tags html

```html
<MudCarouselItem Transition="Transition.Fade" Color="@Color.Transparent">
    <img src="@item.Images.Url" width="500" height="500">
</MudCarouselItem>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand exactly your problem, but tried [this sample](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkQQuFvQaKGUBHwy) and it appears to be working:

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GkQQuFvQaKGUBHwy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).